# How to use connect api in cdp environment salesforce

Tags: apex, connect-api, salesforce-cdp

I am trying to use connectapi to connect to cdp entities like below

```
  public static ConnectApi.CdpQueryMetadataOutput cdpM {get;set;}
    public static ConnectApi.CdpQueryMetadataOutput test1() {   
        cdpM = ConnectApi.CdpQueryMetadataOutput.getProfileMetadata('UnifiedIndividual__dlm');
        return cdpM;
    }
```

Its throwing me compilation error

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void
> getProfileMetadata(String) from the type
> ConnectApi.CdpQueryMetadataOutput

Any idea how to use connectApi methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access a method on the output class. It has no methods.

Instead:

```
cdpM = ConnectAPI.CdpQuery.getProfileMetadata('UnifiedIndividual__dlm');
```